# Evaluating JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a couple of questions about `JAXB`:

1. What options are there for parsing? Can I implement / plugin my own parser easily?
2. What about validity? Suppose I have a relaxed parser that is somewhat relaxed regarding the schema. Can I still create an (invalid) object-structure?
3. Does `JAXB` provide special means to do e.g. validation on the objects? I'd like to parse to an "invalid" object structure, have some algorithm repair it, then validate (in Java).
4. Does `JAXB` provide other means to do fancy things on the objects (e.g. visitor pattern).
5. What about the memory footprint? Is the object representation (disregarding the parsing) feasible for `XML` files of 10-100MB?

Good tutorials covering this kind of questions are appreciated, Google revealed only coarse overviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are my answers to your questions:

> What options are there for parsing? Can I implement / plugin my own
>   parser easily?

JAXB ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) implementations can unmarshal from many different input types:  `InputStream`, `InputSource',`Node`,`XMLStreamReader`,`XMLEventReader`,`File`,`Source`.  If your XML representation matches any of these then you're all set.

> What about validity? Suppose I have a relaxed parser that is somewhat
>   relaxed regarding the schema. Can I still create an (invalid)
>   object-structure?

JAXB implementations requires that the XML be well formed, but does not require it be valid against an XML schema.  It is designed to handle a wide range of documents.  If you want to ensure "validity" then you can set an XML schema (see [JAXB and Marshal/Unmarshal Schema Validation](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html)).

> Does JAXB provide special means to do e.g. validation on the objects?
>   I'd like to parse to an "invalid" object structure, have some
>   algorithm repair it, then validate (in Java).

You can use the `javax.xml.validation` APIs to do validation on an object model.  For a full example see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html

> Does JAXB provide other means to do fancy things on the objects (e.g.
>   visitor pattern).

JAXB models are POJOs so you can design them as you wish.  You may be interested in the following classes:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.Listener.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html

> What about the memory footprint? Is the object representation
>   (disregarding the parsing) feasible for XML files of 10-100MB?

Yes JAXB can be used to process documents of that size.  If you are concerned about size, you can use an `XMLStreamReader` to parse the XML file and then unmarshal objects from the `XMLStreamReader` in chunks.

Comment: Thanks, Blaise this is very helpful. Can you recommend a good book on databinding for XML, also covering designing issues (e.g. mutable / immutable model, dealing with imperfect data)

Comment: @Bastl - I don't have any book recommendations, but I have a pretty active XML & JSON binding blog you may find useful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com